# Python: Runtime Error: EXIT - Program did not return 0

Tags: python

I am trying to solve an IARCS problem, which requires you to input a String and output it word by word in a lexicographic order.

For example, if the input is `Hello I am testing`, the output should be

```
am
hello
i
testing
```

A simplified version of my code is

```
s = input()
s = s.lower()
s1 = list(s.split())
s1.sort()
for i in range(len(s1)):
    print(s1[i])
```

It works correctly for all the testing cases.

But the auto-judge gives me this error:

```
Runtime Error: EXIT
Description: Program did not return 0
```

What does this mean?

PyCharm tells that "Process finished with exit code 0".

Why am I still getting this error?

Edit: Link of problem: http://opc.iarcs.org.in/index.php/problems/WORDLIST

Comment: What is IARCS? Can you quote the exact problem description?

Comment: IARCS is "Indian Association for Research in Computer Science". It conducts a programming olympiad for High School students. I just updated the link of the problem.

Comment: I am not sure that this is what the error message is referring to, but according to the problem description you are supposed to output the number of distinct words first.

Comment: Yes, I have done that in the full code. There is even code to remove all the commas, semicolons, etc and also the redundant words. I have just posted the main part of the code here since the full code is a bit long. I am getting the desired output, but I don't understand what the error means.